# Android kapt java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError Room

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

I'm updating my project to use the jetpack libraries.

I executed this in the commandline:

```
./gradlew :app:kaptDebugKotlin
```

in my project directory, and this error was thrown:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8([BI)V
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(NativeDB.java:71)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:174)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:220)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
        at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier$Companion.create(DatabaseVerifier.kt:81)
        at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:78)
        at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:54)
        at androidx.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:63)
        at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
        at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:99)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:216)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:164)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:370)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:61)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:361)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:126)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:50)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:405)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:927)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:957)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:926)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:404)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**This is my project build.gradle**

```
ext {
archLifecycleVersion = '2.0.0'
roomVersion = '2.1.0-alpha02'
pagingVersion = '2.1.0-beta01'

supportLibVersion = '1.0.0'
```

}

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And this is the app build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "package.name.of.app"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            //multiDexEnabled false
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4096m"
        }
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
        kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

        // architecture components
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
        implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$rootProject.pagingVersion"
        kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what caused this issue? Why does the SQLite error occur during compilation instead of during actual execution? Also, has anyone successfully compiled an app with similar dependencies as described above?

Comment: this `build.gradle` has more problems than only the one...

Comment: Hi @MartinZeitler, could you please describe the problem you see in the build.gradle file? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Upon searching for information regarding this issue, I found this link

https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/97

The fix was to update /etc/fstab to remove 'noexec' from /tmp, and then remounting /tmp

Answer (score 0):

In Windows grant all permissions to your user in c:\Users\\AppData\Temp and the problem will be gone.
You'll have to do it everytime you update Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have permissions to remove `noexec` from `/tmp`, you can also supply an alternative `java.io.tmpdir` to `kapt`:

A [Room issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111631291) has a [comment from a Google engineer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111631291#comment3) with a workaround:

> Since you are using `kapt` are you sure you are passing `java.io.tmpdir` to Kotlin's compiler daemon and not Gradle's?

> For example:
>
> ```
> ./gradlew <gradle-params> -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Djava.io.tmpdir=path/to/a/folder" <task>
> ```

Another [Room issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65162948) has a [comment from a Google engineer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65162948#comment12) suggesting that upgrading to `2.2.5` fixes the problem:

> Can you try with [`Room 2.2.5`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_225_3) we had some further fixes in that version regarding the JDBC library and the way the Room compiler loads it and uses it.

I upgraded to `2.2.5`, and the problem went away, but I didn't see this failure on every build, so I'll have to wait couple of weeks before I can say this is definitely fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was AdoptOpenJDK installed via Homebrew. According to [this issue](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/issues/1211) some versions of the JDK distributed via Homebrew are not notarized.

I solved this by uninstalling from Homebrew and re-installing AdoptOpenJDK from the .pkg file downloaded from their site.